# How to obtain the body of a retrofit request when it fails?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava with retrofit. I want to know how can I retrieve the BODY/RAW sent by the request when it fails or success.

This is my controller calling the API:

```
ChatMessage body = new ChatMessage();
    ...
    //configuration of body variable is omitted.
    ...

chatController.sendMessage(body).subscribe(this::onSendMessageSuccess, this::onSendMessageError);
```

And these are the methods to receive the answer:

```
private void onSendMessageSuccess(ChatRestResponse response) {
   // How can I get the "ChatMessage body" sent in at first by the re
}

private void onSendMessageError(Throwable throwable) {
     // How can I get the "ChatMessage body" sent in at first by the request       
}
```

I want to know how can I get the ChatMessage class that I used to make the request.

**JUST FOR REFERENCES**

This is my interface:

```
@Headers({
     "Accept: application/json",
     "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST(URL)
Observable<ChatRestResponse> sendMessage(
     @Header("Authorization") String token,
     @Body ChatMessage body);
```

This is my controller that calls the api:

```
public Observable<ChatRestResponse> sendMessage(ChatMessage body) {
     String accessToken = mPref.getAccesToken();

     return mChatApi.sendMessage(accessToken , body)
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Brother On Failure there is no body exists in response. There would be just some code associated with the error it faces. like 404 etc.
But if you are talking about your own server response that is on failed. Like if you login to you account from you app by Retrofit. If you enter wrong credentials, internet and connection with server is all OK, Even then the the response will run the function `onResponce()` . But here you can check the server internal error that the server will send associated with the type or error.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            //All is well
                            // you can get body here as 
                            String token = responce.body().getToken();
                            //etc
                        } else {
                           //Something went wrong like password etc
                           //You can check the body here also in case of failure
                           //Which is due to some internal server error
                           //because of wrong credentials
                           //But this response is in failure and also have a body 
                           //I guess this is what u want
                           String failuerToken = responce.getBody().getAccessToken();
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                                    .setMessage("Invalid Credentials")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Try Again", null)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                        showProgress(false);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                                .setMessage("Unable to reach server")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Try Again", null)
                                .show();
                        call.cancel();
                    }
                });
```

**NOTE THAT**

```
LoginResponse
```

Is my own Class

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    public String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    public String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    public Integer expiresIn;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = apiInterface.Login(requestData);
```

See I'm sending data by using `requestData` . The Only Solution to your problem is Make a seperate package name `urils`, make a class `RequestData` and put some static variables in it.

```
public class RequestData {
    public static String username;
    public static String password;
    public static String email;
    public static Int age;
    //etc
}
```

Set the variable values like this

```
RequestData.username = "abcd";
RequestData.password = "abcd";
RequestData.email = "abcd@email.com";
RequestData.age = 20";
```

Then send the data through the `api call`.

After failure use this class to access the previous data from it and display it on UI respectively.

Comment: @Deneb Chorny This is Perfect answer.. On Failure there is no body exists in response,so u have to use callback's onFailure method.

Comment: The answer is great, I already knew about this, and thanks for answering. But I wonder there is no way to make an interceptor? I mean. I want that if there is an error or success to be able the get the object I sent as raw/body. 

why? because I want to update the UI in the exact object that create the request. I hope there is a solution

Comment: @DenebChorny Please see the Update in the answer above

Comment: It's not RxJava

Comment: If I use static variables imagine making multiple requests. I have asked the question for that reason, otherwise it would not be necessary to even use static variables.

Comment: Bro in this case you have to build a logic according to your own requirements. Maybe you can use Lists or arrays inside the RequestData class that is static. Because the thing you are asking for is not a problem, its the logic of your app. Try multiple ways to do this, I hope it'll be done soon :)